# "Check All" checkbox shows ambiguous behaviour with pagination

Tags: javascript, php

thanks for being so supportive to the topics asked. I have a built a 'User Approval' system wherein the admin gets list of registered users and approves them by using checkboxes for each and 'Check all' that selects all users. Table has pagination of 10 users at once. My issue here is when I 'check all' on the second page with 10 users, the table automatically selects and displays the first 10 users also i.e. the first page with 10 users. How can I stop the page to second list only when "check all" is implemented on second list of 10 candidates. I am confused on where it has gone wrong and getting no clue . Any help or advice will be appreciated and helpful. Here is the code for javascript that I have used,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var select_all = document.getElementById("select_all"); //select all checkbox
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"); //checkbox items
//select all checkboxes
select_all.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { 
        checkboxes[i].checked = select_all.checked;
    }
});
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){ //".checkbox" change 
        //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if(this.checked == false){
            select_all.checked = false;
        }
        //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
        if(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked').length == checkboxes.length){
            select_all.checked = true;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And the php+html for the table header "Check all"

```
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> class="checkbox" value= "<?php //echo $row['id']; ?>"> </th>
```

And my pagination class,

```
<?php
class pagination

  {

    var $page = 1; // Current Page

    var $perPage = 10; // Items on each page, defaulted to 10

    var $showFirstAndLast = false; // if you would like the first and last page options.



    function generate($array, $perPage = 10)

    {

      // Assign the items per page variable

      if (!empty($perPage))

        $this->perPage = $perPage;



      // Assign the page variable

      if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {

        $this->page = $_GET['page']; // using the get method

      } else {

        $this->page = 1; // if we don't have a page number then assume we are on the first page

      }



      // Take the length of the array

      $this->length = count($array);



      // Get the number of pages

      $this->pages = ceil($this->length / $this->perPage);



      // Calculate the starting point 

      $this->start  = ceil(($this->page - 1) * $this->perPage);



      // Return the part of the array we have requested

      return array_slice($array, $this->start, $this->perPage);

    }
function links()

    {

      // Initiate the links array

      $plinks = array();

      $links = array();

      $slinks = array();
// Concatenate the get variables to add to the page numbering string

      if (count($_GET)) {

        $queryURL = '';

        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

          if ($key != 'page') {

            $queryURL .= '&'.$key.'='.$value;

          }

        }

      }
 // If we have more then one pages

      if (($this->pages) > 1)

      {
// Assign the 'previous page' link into the array if we are not on the first page

        if ($this->page != 1) {

          if ($this->showFirstAndLast) {

            $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page=1'.$queryURL.'">&laquo;&laquo; First </a> ';

          }

          $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page - 1).$queryURL.'">&laquo; Prev</a> ';

        }
 // Assign all the page numbers & links to the array

        for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {

          if ($this->page == $j) {

            $links[] = ' <a style="font-weight: bold;">'.$j.'</a> '; // If we are on the same page as the current item

          } else {

            $links[] = ' <a href="?page='.$j.$queryURL.'">'.$j.'</a> '; // add the link to the array

          }

        }
 // Assign the 'next page' if we are not on the last page

        if ($this->page < $this->pages) {

          $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';

          if ($this->showFirstAndLast) {

            $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->pages).$queryURL.'"> Last &raquo;&raquo; </a> ';

          }

        }
// Push the array into a string using any some glue

        return implode(' ', $plinks).implode($this->implodeBy, $links).implode(' ', $slinks);
 }
return;

    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: this likely has to do with how you implemented the pagination. When you go from page 1 to 2, the checkboxes from page 1 are still present somewhere in the page DOM and thus are captured by the jQuery selector.

Comment: Can you share your pagination logic also look like your are keeping all the checkbox element in page DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the time @Calimero. But even though I am not selecting anything from first list and I move to the second list, still it selects the first list and displays the first list instead of staying at second list.

Comment: @AnilYadav Thanks for the time mate. The pagination is a class made for tables. You want me to share that?

Comment: @Ansh yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. When you skip from page 1 to 2, inspect the html with your browser dev tools and paste the snippet (containing both pages) in the question, in order to update the faulty jQuery selector

Comment: Yep same here @Ansh - Just make sure it's not containing both pagination elements.

Comment: @Calimero I am sorry but I am not sure how this should to be done, can you please guide me through this.

Comment: 1/ Open the dev tools in your web browser of choice, source tab. 2/ Go to the page, skip from page #1 to #2. Observe the html updating and copy the relevant snippet in your question above

Comment: @AnilYadav May I know how can I check it. I am new to web development and not known much about the dev tools. It will be a new learning for me. Big thanks in advance

Comment: I have firebug installed in here and I am using firefox for browser. Should I check the 'html' tab in there? @Calimero

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Right-click + inspect with firebug (Firefox)/ Inspect (Chrome)

Comment: @Calimero I have done as you said but the html tab as you suggested shows the same code for both #1 and #2. Anything else to check on?

Comment: @AnilYadav Thanks Anil. Have tried doing it but seems no change for the two pages in the html

Comment: well, in that case as @AnilYadav suggested post the pagination class source code.

Comment: Just updated my code with the pagination class. Please take a look. @AnilYadav